# change utf8 language in python3.8.3

Tags: python, json, api, flask

i want to show my language but it show utf-8 instead
my python version is 3.8.3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Server Side
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api,Resource,abort,reqparse,marshal_with,fields
import json
import requests

app=Flask(__name__)
api=Api(app)

##input  
def getbotnoi(self,name):
    return name

#design
class WeatherCity(Resource):
    def get(self,name):
        return getbotnoi(self,name)
   
#call
api.add_resource(WeatherCity,"/w/<string:name>")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

it show utf8 when it isnt eng language

[eg.thai language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3cwu.jpg)

Comment: This line `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` was only needed for Python 2

Comment: That is your language in correctly encoded JSON. In order to view it in a browser it should be processed by JavaScript. Remember you are defining a (technical) API.

Comment: "it doesnt work" is a really bad description. It neither tells us what happens nor what you expected. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flask application is working as intended. You are sending the string in different language, and it gets UTF-8 encoded when you are returning the response.

Since you are using flask_restful, by default, the response will always be a JSON value, in this case a [JSON string](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). The default way to write non-ASCII characters in strings is with `\u` prefix. Moreover, the browser doesn't know how to render this `\u` prefixed string.

You can use just flask to return the response as-is rather than JSON encoding:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Server Side

from flask import Flask
from flask.views import MethodView

app = Flask(__name__)


def getbotnoi(self, name):
    return name


class WeatherCity(MethodView):
    def get(self, name):
        return getbotnoi(self, name)


app.add_url_rule("/w/<string:name>", view_func=WeatherCity.as_view("weather"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

By default, here the `Content-Type` would be `text/html; charset=utf-8`, which will instruct the browser to render it properly.

Comment: thank you. but can it call created API?
and real getbotnoi function is json output.it still work?

Comment: If the response needs to be in JSON, then \u string is fine (your original approach). Most probably, the front-end code will convert JSON to proper format before displaying it. It's just that you cannot view the response directly in the browser. Try opening the same in Firefox, which will render JSON string in proper way.